# Fetching Async TreeView Data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to react and I'm building a `TreeView` component in react where I fetch data as nodes are expanded. I'm using the TreeView from Material UI: https://material-ui.com/api/tree-view/

I have created the component below which fetches data when a node is expanded. MyTreeItem is a custom version expanding the original with a fetch call. But I'm confused on how to display the childnodes. How can I do this?

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";
import TreeView from "@material-ui/lab/TreeView";
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ExpandMore";
import ChevronRightIcon from "@material-ui/icons/ChevronRight";
import TreeItem from "@material-ui/lab/TreeItem";
const { useState, useCallback } = React;

export default function MyTreeItem({ id, name }) {
  const [childNodes, setChildNodes] = useState(null);
  const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState([]);

  function fakeAjax(url) {
    return fetch(url).then(res => {
      if (!res.ok) {
        throw new Error("HTTP error " + res.status);
      }
      return res.json();
    });
  }

  function fetchChildNodes(id) {
    // Should in reality be "URL/id", but fake JSON for now
    return fakeAjax(`https://api.myjson.com/bins/1aqhsc`);
  }

  const handleChange = (event, nodes) => {
    const expandingNodes = nodes.filter(x => !expanded.includes(x));
    setExpanded(nodes);
    if (expandingNodes[0]) {
      const childId = expandingNodes[0];
      fetchChildNodes(childId).then(result =>
        setChildNodes(result.children.map(node => <MyTreeItem {...node} />))
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <TreeView
      defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
      defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
      expanded={expanded}
      onNodeToggle={handleChange}
    >
      {/*The node below should act as the root node for now */}
      <TreeItem nodeId="1" label="Applications">
        {/*The childnodes should be here*/}
      </TreeItem>
    </TreeView>
  );
}
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<MyTreeItem />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your example, it seems, you are trying to build the tree where each node that has children will also be a tree.

In this case, render will look like this:

```
{/*The node below should act as the root node for now */}
<TreeItem nodeId={props.id} label={props.name}>
    {childNodes || [<div key="stub" />]} // stub div is used so user could see expand icon
</TreeItem>
// you also need to pass props for root items
ReactDOM.render(<MyTreeItem id="1" name="Applications" />, rootElement);
```

You can check the working code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-k5ol6

There are multiple ways to render a tree. One is to model a tree structure and render it in a way so each node that has children would no longer be a whole another tree with local state, like in your implementation. The advantage of this approach is that you can provide a complete tree via props, not only by fetching it on 'expand' action.

Here's the example of such an approach: https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-h6zfe

Also, you could render the tree as a list, where each nested level has an offset specified via styles. This has an advantage when you need to have a pagination on each level separately (in case if a single level has a lot of items). The implementation is not as easy as in the cases above, so I will not provide an example.

Comment: Thank you, I will also be looking at some of the other approaches¨

Comment: Is it possible to fetch data when expanding a node with your second approach?

Comment: It's in the example. Check out handleChange function. It has a setTimeout function that emulates an xhr call. You can replace the body of handleChange (you can also pass any args that you need for your xhr call) fn with your own logic to fetch data on expand.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using a recursive function to build the children.  You can see how I have done this in typescript.  I have used the includeChildren variable to improve performance by only drawing the items which are on screen.

```
const displayChildren = (parent: DataItem, isRoot: boolean) => {
    var includeChildren = isRoot;
    if (includeChildren === false && expanded) {
        for (let expandedItem of expanded) {
            const id = parseInt(expandedItem);
            if (id === parent.id || id === parent.parentId) {
                includeChildren = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    const children = includeChildren && childrenLookup?.get(parent.id);
    return (
        <TreeItem key={parent.id} nodeId={'' + parent.id} label={parent.name} >
            {children && children.map((c: DataItem) => displayChildren(c, false))}
        </TreeItem>
    )
}
```

I have stored the expanded items in react state, as per the [Controlled tree view](https://v4.mui.com/components/tree-view/#controlled-tree-view) example. You can return the TreeView like this:

```
return (
    <TreeView
        defaultCollapseIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}
        defaultExpandIcon={<ChevronRightIcon />}
        style={{ height: 240, flexGrow: 1, maxWidth: 400, overflowY: 'auto' }}
        expanded={expanded}
        selected={selected}
        onNodeToggle={handleToggle}
        onNodeSelect={handleSelect}
    >
        {dataItems && getRootItems(dataItems).map((parent) => displayChildren(parent, true))}
    </TreeView>)
```

I found that using a childrenLookup is really quick so you don't need to fetch data from the API.  My treeview has 10,000 items and it still works fine.

If you are wondering how the lookup works, this is how I have done it.  The data is coming from a mobx store but you could use any API response, just make sure it's only called once.

```
const [childrenLookup, setChildrenLookup] = React.useState<Map<number, DataItem[]>>();
React.useEffect(() => {
    let lookup = new Map<number, DataItem[]>();
    if (dataStore.dataItems) {
        for (let dataItem of dataStore.dataItems) {
            if (dataItem.parentId) {
                if (!lookup.has(dataItem.parentId)) {
                    lookup.set(dataItem.parentId, []);
                }
                lookup.get(dataItem.parentId)?.push(dataItem);
            }
        }
        setChildrenLookup(lookup);
    }
}, [dataStore.dataItems])
```

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the answer of SciFiThief, it seems TreeView components are recursively nested, which is not ideal.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31404004)